# US region phone number formatting with extensions on Edittext in android?

Tags: android, phone-number, telephonymanager

My requirement is such that user should be enabled to enter number in edittext which must be formatted for the United States with 3 digit area code & then 7 digits. Extensions are allowed by using an x before them. Edittext must be able to take an extension (using an x), such as – (617) 874-4545 x118.

Currently I am using the following

```
editTextPhone.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher("US"));
```

which appends '-' & '()' to number entered automatically. This is partially correct, but how do I append the x in the number.

Any help regarding this shall be appreciated.